# ¿Como obtener el id de mi usuario logueado con httpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

espero me puedan apoyar con un tema que no puedo resolver, estoy tratando de obtener el Id me mi usuario cuando ingresa al sistema, ya que cada uno tiene distinta data.
Lo estoy tratando de obtener con `httpContext` pero me llega el objeto en nulo.

Este es mi método:

```
    public class ServicioUsuario: IServicioUsuario
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public ServicioUsuario(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public int ObtenerIdUsuario()
    {
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var idClaim = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();
            var id = int.Parse(idClaim.Value);
            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("El usuario no esta autenticado");
        }
    }

}
```

Asi es como lo mando a llamar en mi controlador:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var idUsuario = servicioUsuario.ObtenerIdUsuario();
        var candidatos = await repositorioCandidato.ObtenerCandidatos(idUsuario);

        return View(candidatos);
    }
```

Este es mi método para iniciar sesión:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IniciarSesion(string email, string password)
    {
        UsuarioModel usuarioEncontrado = await usuarioServicio.GetUsuario(email, Utilidades.Utilidades.EncriptarPassword(password));

        if(usuarioEncontrado == null)
        {
            TempData["mensaje"] = "No se encontraron coincidencias";
            return View();
        }

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuarioEncontrado.Nombre)
        };

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh= true
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            properties
        );

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Este es el error que me arroja, pero es por que no recolecta nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan apoyar si estoy realizando algo mal o si hay una mejor manera de realizarlo, se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Pero, guardaste alguna claim?? que tiene esa lista? la revisaste?

Comment: Hola, si! modifique la respuesta e implemente el método donde hago el inicio de sesión y ahi creo una lista de claims

Comment: pon un punto de interrupción y ve si esas variables no te devuelve algún valor nulo

Comment: Si! `var idClaim = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault();` esa es la que me da nulo y es por eso que me da ese error. Pero no se por que no me da la información que pido.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré el error y era muy obvio, no configure el `NameIdentifier` a la hora de que creaba la lista de los claims. Debe de quedar asi:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IniciarSesion(string email, string password)
    {
        UsuarioModel usuarioEncontrado = await usuarioServicio.GetUsuario(email, Utilidades.Utilidades.EncriptarPassword(password));

        if(usuarioEncontrado == null)
        {
            TempData["mensaje"] = "No se encontraron coincidencias";
            return View();
        }

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuarioEncontrado.Nombre),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, usuarioEncontrado.IdUsuario.ToString())
        };

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh= true
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            properties
        );

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Espero que les ayude.